# Best approach to replicate a complex piece of solidity code in Javascript/Typescript

Tags: evm, ethereumjs

I am working on replicating a piece of complex Solidity and assembly code in Typescript and I wonder what would be the best way to approach this. Is it for example possible to execute a piece of Solidity code in EthereumJS implementaion of EVM? And if yes would be usable in a frontend application with good enough performance?

I am working on reimplementing [this code](https://xn--2-umb.com/21/muldiv/index.html) and I would like to avoid calling a node.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deploying the solidity code to local Javascript EVM worked great. [Here](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-monorepo/blob/master/packages/vm/examples/run-solidity-contract/index.ts) is how it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

The example is also simple to implement in JavaScript/TypeScript by using the native JS **`bigint`** type. The opcodes `add`, `mul` is trivial to implement, you must just handle the `uint256` overflows.

```typescript
const UINT256_SIZE = 2n**256n;
const UINT256_MAX = UINT256_SIZE - 1n;
const UINT256_MIN = 0n;

const INT256_MAX = (UINT256_SIZE / 2n) - 1n;
const INT256_MIN = -UINT256_SIZE / 2n;

function mul (a: bigint, b: bigint): bigint {
    return uint256(a * b);
}
function uint256(x: bigint): bigint {
    return unchecked(x, UINT256_SIZE, UINT256_MIN, UINT256_MAX);
}
function int256(x: bigint): bigint {
    return unchecked(x, UINT256_SIZE, INT256_MIN, INT256_MAX);
}

function unchecked (a: bigint, size: bigint, min: bigint, max: bigint) {
    a = a % size;
    a = a > max ? (a - size) : a;
    a = a < min ? (a + size) : a;
    return a;
}
```

The complete implementation - [$opcodes.ts](https://github.com/0xweb-org/dequanto/blob/2ef71a9c2ee9f634f5e30b0e47ef93178bece884/src/evm/functions/$opcodes.ts)

Then the contracts code will look almost similar, with some simple ***syntax modifications***:

```typescript
namespace MulDiv {
    export function muldiv(a: bigint, b: bigint, denominator: bigint): bigint {
        
        require(denominator > 0);

        let mm = mulmod(a, b, not(0n));
        let prod0 = mul(a, b)
        let prod1 = sub(sub(mm, prod0), lt(mm, prod0))
    
        if (prod1 == 0n) {
            return div(prod0, denominator);
        }
        
        require(prod1 < denominator);

        let remainder = mulmod(a, b, denominator);
        
        prod1 = sub(prod1, gt(remainder, prod0))
        prod0 = sub(prod0, remainder)
        
        let twos = -denominator & denominator;
        denominator = div(denominator, twos)
        
        prod0 = div(prod0, twos)
        twos = add(div(sub(0n, twos), twos), 1n)

        prod0 |= prod1 * twos;
        
        let inv = 3n * denominator ^ 2n;
        
        inv *= 2n - denominator * inv; 
        inv *= 2n - denominator * inv; 
        inv *= 2n - denominator * inv; 
        inv *= 2n - denominator * inv; 
        inv *= 2n - denominator * inv; 
        inv *= 2n - denominator * inv; 
        
        let result = prod0 * inv;
        return result;
    }
}
```